# how to send post data on the chrome.downloads.download method?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to use the chrome.downloads.download method and i need to send post data to the server, i use options.body="?keyName=value" on the download options but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows better the api, the documentation is not very explicit about this subject.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is the server seeing anything? Are you getting a client-side error? One observation: it's odd that you're starting the POST body with a question mark; that's typically the query string delimiter in a GET. A properly x-www-form-urlencoded POST body would have keyName=value with no question mark.

Comment: You are right about the ?, but even without it the server doesn't seems to be receiving anything. Im not seeing any error on the client, just downloads the html instead of the file because the post is wrong. I wrote a script in php that gives  to me a file if i send a value by post or print $_REQUEST if not, and this always is empty.

Comment: It'd be easier for us to help if you posted your code and the extension's manifest. Otherwise it'll be a game of 20 questions (e.g., have you declared the proper host permission?).

Answer (score 0):

'cause Chrome doesn't set request content-type for you, you can verify this through this script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"');
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); // $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
?>
```

So, you should use `parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $post_params)` to get the values of the parameters. PHP won't parse the post body if content-type is not properly set. (application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/www-url-encoded, etc.)